# Cannot find either column "dba" or the user-defined function or aggregate "schema.functionName", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: functions

I created a function and granted select on `[dba].[ufn_track_dailies]` to `public`.  The function shows up under table valued functions, but when I try to use it I get an error:

```
select [dba].[ufn_track_dailies]('Real Name','', '08-01-2015', '08-31-2015')
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using ???

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for SQL Server (and maybe others as well?), then you cannot `SELECT` a TVF, you need to `SELECT` *FROM* a TVF ;-) And, you need to use those silly parenthesis when calling functions:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [dba].ufn_track_dailies();
```

If it were a scalar function, that would be:

```sql
SELECT [dba].ufn_track_dailies();
```